# How to clear Addressables Cache?

Tags: unity, c#, assets, asset-management, addressable

I am loading my assets and tile information through YAML files.

While working on the game, I need to quickly change some values and test them in-game, and I can re-load the YAML information without having to restart.

In the old Resources system, this would be done by using AssetDatabase.Refresh(), after which I could re-load the YAML files and get new data. However, Addressables handles this differently. Based on some research and [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-clear-cached-addressables-cant-catch-downloading-error-exception.715094/) forum, I've tried the following two options:

```
Addressables.ClearDependencyCacheAsync(allLocations);
Caching.ClearCache();
```

Sadly, neither of these has worked.

How can I clear the cached Addressables data so I can reload it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the Unity team has done some updates to addressables, but reloading them seems to work now. I simply clear out my existing `Dictionary` full of loaded assets, and just call the `LoadAssets` method again.

This has been tested in version `2021.2.11f1`.